# How does += (plus equal) work?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused with the += sign. How does it work?

1. `1 += 2` // equals ?
2. and this

   ```
   var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
   var sum = 0;
   data.forEach(function(value) {
       sum += value; 
   });
   sum = ?
   ```

Comment: After `1 += 2` 1 is equal 3. Not all that much of a problem. But `1 -= 1;` makes boolean expressions a pain in the neck!

Comment: Stating the obvious -- you could try this in the JavaScript console of your browser: after the forEach, sum is 15.

Comment: Didn't know you could do this inline using the value.

Answer (score 90):

`1 += 2` is a syntax error (left-side must be a variable).

`x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y`.

Comment: This is buggy as hell in javascript tho, according to javascript:
198.51 -= 84.4 results in 114.10999999999999
Which is incorrect.

Comment: @JpHouten Your comment isn't really on this answer, but even still I felt I should reply to it.  First, you mean -, not -= since you 198.51 -= 84.4 just gives an error.  But mostly, this isn't a bug.  This is just a consequence of the fact that computers represent numbers in binary instead of decimal and numbers like 198.51 and 84.4 can't be represented exactly in binary, but have to be rounded.  This is a standard part of floating point numbers.  If you need exact (rather than approximate) decimal calculations, you should use fixed point numbers instead.

Comment: Actually x+=y equals to x = x + (y). Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65325247/2913723

Answer (score 32):

1) 1 += 2 // equals ?

That is syntactically invalid. The left side must be a variable. For example.

```
var mynum = 1;
mynum += 2;
// now mynum is 3.
```

`mynum += 2;` is just a short form for `mynum = mynum + 2;`

2)

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sum = 0;
data.forEach(function(value) {
    sum += value; 
});
```

Sum is now 15.
Unrolling the forEach we have:

```
var sum = 0;
sum += 1; // sum is 1
sum += 2; // sum is 3
sum += 3; // sum is 6
sum += 4; // sum is 10
sum += 5; // sum is 15
```

Answer (score 19):

That is just a short form for:

```
sum = sum + value;
```

Answer (score 13):

`+=` in JavaScript (as well as in many other languages) adds the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side, storing the result in that variable.  Your example of `1 +=2` therefore does not make sense.  Here is an example:

```
var x = 5;
x += 4; // x now equals 9, same as writing x = x + 4;
x -= 3; // x now equals 6, same as writing x = x - 3;
x *= 2; // x now equals 12, same as writing x = x * 2;
x /= 3; // x now equals 4, same as writing x = x / 3;
```

In your specific example the loop is summing the numbers in the array `data`.

Answer (score 5):

`+=` operator is used to concatenate strings or add numbers.

It will increment your sum variable with the amount next to it.

```
var sum = 0;
var valueAdded = 5; 

sum += valueAdded;
```

> sum = 5

Comment: It concatenates strings but adds numbers.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Concatenate was probably not the best term ;)

Comment: So would that make `+=` = `.=` relating to php?

Answer (score 4):

You have to know that:

- Assignment operators syntax is: `variable = expression;`

  For this reason `1 += 2` -> `1 = 1 + 2` is not a valid syntax as the left operand isn't a variable. The error in this case is `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`.
- `x += y` is the short form for `x = x + y`, where `x` is the variable and `x + y` the expression.

  The result of the sum is **15**.

```
      sum = 0;
      sum = sum + 1; // 1
      sum = sum + 2; // 3
      sum = sum + 3; // 6
      sum = sum + 4; // 10
      sum = sum + 5; // 15
```

Other [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) shortcuts works the same way (relatively to the standard operations they refer to).
.

Answer (score 3):

...and don't forget what happens when you mix types:

```
x = 127;
x += " hours "
// x is now a string: "127 hours "
x += 1 === 0;
// x is still a string: "127 hours false"
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone said above

```js
var str = "foo"
str += " bar"
console.log(str) //will now give you "foo bar"
```

Check this out as well https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/

Comment: Did you mean will give you "foo bar"? You should try your answer in your browser.

Comment: Fixed with a small edit.  It had previously said "no" instead of "now", which is what Mark was replying to.

Answer (score 1):

`a += b` is shorthand for `a = a +b` which means:

1) `1 += 2` // won't compile

2) 15

Answer (score 1):

that's just a shorthand notation in most languages.which means that

> x=x+1;

we can do the same operation for **x-=1,x*=1,x/=1**;
which means

### > x=x-1; x=x*1; x=x/1;

Answer (score 0):

`x+=y` is shorthand in many languages for `set x to x + y`.  The sum will be, as hinted by its name, the sum of the numbers in `data`.

Answer (score -1):

NO  `1+=2!=2` it means 
you are going to add `1+2`.
But this will give you a syntax error.
Assume if a variable is int type int `a=1`;
then
`a+=2`; means `a=1+2`; and increase the value of a from 1 to 3.

Answer (score -1):

`x += 1` is just shorthand for `x = x + 1`
It can also be used for strings:

```
var string = "foo"
string += "bar"
```

Answer (score -2):

1. `1 += 2` won't throw an error but you still shouldn't do it. In this statement you are basically saying "set 1 equal to 1 + 2" but 1 is a constant number and not a variable of type `:number` or `:string` so it probably wouldn't do anything.  Saying

   ```js
   var myVariable = 1
   myVariable += 2
   console.log(myVariable)
   ```

   would log `3` to the console, as `x += y` is just short for `x = x + y`
2. ```js
   var data = [1,2,3,4,5]
   var sum
   data.forEach(function(value){
     sum += value
   })
   ```

   would make `sum` = 15 because:

   ```
   sum += 1 //sum = 1
   sum += 2 //sum = 3
   sum += 3 //sum = 6
   sum += 4 //sum = 10
   sum += 5 //sum = 15
   ```