# What does it mean to add to innerHTML with + in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading, operators, innerhtml

I know how the `innerHTML` works in JavaScript like in following function:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="changetext();">
        <div id="pp" onClick="changetext();">Click here</div>
        <script>
            function changetext(){
                document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = "New Content!";  
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This results in `"New Content"`.
But  I have also come across many examples where `innerHTML` was used with the `+` or `+=` operator like in this [W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_addeventlistener_add_many2). What does it mean when I add to `innerHTML` using `+`?

Comment: `+=` is used for **Concatenation** of string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does += (plus equal) work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826260/how-does-plus-equal-work)

Answer (score 4):

`elem.innerHTML +="abc"` means that it will **append** `abc` to the `innerHTML` of `elem`.

`elem.innerHTML +="abc"`

is equivalent to

`elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + "abc"`

Answer (score 1):

You use `innertHTML+` when you have to append new content in existing content. If you use `innerHTML = "New Content"` that would replace all content in `pp` and place "New Content" there, but `innerHTML+="New Content"` would append this with existing content.

As other people also mentioned `innerHTML += "New Content"` is equivalent to `element.innerHMTL = element.innerHMTL + "New Content"`, so this means that the `+=` is basically used to append content. It can be used to append/add new values and at the same time can be used to increment an `int` value so `i++` = `i+=1` = `i = i+1`

Comment: Worth mentioning is that `a += b` is shorthand for `a = a + b`

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` operator appends the text to the elements current content.

Answer (score 0):

> An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on
> the value of its right operand. The basic assignment operator is equal
> (=), which assigns the value of its right operand to its left operand.
> That is, x = y assigns the value of y to x.
>
> The other assignment operators are shorthand for the operations listed in the following table:

```
Shorthand operator  |     Meaning
--------------------------------------
| x += y            |     x = x + y    |
----------------------------------------
| x -= y            |     x = x - y    |
----------------------------------------
| x *= y            |     x = x * y    |
----------------------------------------
| x /= y            |     x = x / y    |
----------------------------------------
| x %= y            |     x = x % y    |
----------------------------------------
| x <<= y           |     x = x << y   |
----------------------------------------
| x >>= y           |     x = x >> y   |
----------------------------------------
| x >>>= y          |     x = x >>> y  |
----------------------------------------
| x &= y            |     x = x & y    |
----------------------------------------
| x ^= y            |     x = x ^ y    |
----------------------------------------
| x |= y            |     x = x | y    |
----------------------------------------
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators

The spec defines these "shorthand" operators as *Compound Assignment ( op= )*

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2

So based from your example, if:

```
element.innerHTML = 'foo';
```

then:

```
element.innerHTML += 'bar';
```

is the same as:

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + 'bar';
```

which results in:

```
console.log(element.innerHTML); // "foobar"
```

Comment: The aren't "shorthand" operators, they're [*compound assignment* operators](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2).