# join() function doesnt work in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried using the join() function in my array and tried to document.write it but
the console says"birth.join() is not a function "

```
birthyear=[];

for(i=1800;i<2018;i++){
birthyear+=i
}

birth=birthyear.join();

document.write(birth);
```

Comment: `console.log(birthyear);` would’ve revealed the reason for the error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3746725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) works on array and to insert an element to array you should call [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) instead of `+=`, read more about += [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826260/how-does-plus-equal-work/6826284).

Always use `var` before declaring variables, or you end up declaring global variables.

```js
var birthyear = [];

for (i = 1800; i < 2018; i++) {
  birthyear.push(i);
}

var birth = birthyear.join(", ");

document.write(birth);
```

Answer (score 1):

I your code your not appending data to array you are adding data to array variable which is wrong

> 1st Way
>
> ```
> birthyear=[]; 
> for(i=1800;i<2018;i++)
> { 
>     birthyear.push(i); 
> } 
> birth=birthyear.join(); 
> document.write(birth);
> ```
>
> 2nd Way
>
> ```
> birthyear=[];
> k=0;
> for(i=1800;i<2018;i++){
> birthyear[k++]=i;
> }
>
> birth=birthyear.join();
>
> document.write(birth);
> ```

Comment: or you can use     birthyear=[];
    
    for(i=1800;i<2018;i++){
    birthyear.push(i);
    }
    
    birth=birthyear.join();
    
    document.write(birth);

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply .push() to a primitive type but to an array type (Object type).
You declared `var birthyear = [];` as an array but in the body of your loop you used it as a primitive:  `birthyear+=i;`.

Here's a revision:

```js
var birthyear=[];

for(let i=1800;i<2018;i++){
    birthyear[i]=i;  
   // careful here:   birthyear[i] += i; won't work 
   // since birthyear[i] is NaN
}

var birth = birthyear.join("\n");

document.write(birth);
```

Happy coding! ^_^