# why this script can print like this

Tags: javascript

```
var dollar = '$';
for (var i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
    console.log(dollar);
    dollar += '$';
}
```

I just start learning javascript, please help to explain why the script can print like this. Thx for help

```
$
$$
$$$
$$$$
$$$$$
$$$$$$
```

Comment: What don't you understand?  In each iteration of the loop, it prints out the current value of `dollar`, which is some number of `$` signs.  Also, in each iteration, the loop adds one more `$` to end of `dollar`, so it keeps growing by one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What is it about the code that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand this line " dollar += '$'; "
if I skip this line, it will turn to 6 times of $$$$$$

Comment: If you remove `dollar += '$';` it should print `$` six times, not `$$$$$$` six times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does += (plus equal) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826260/how-does-plus-equal-work)

Comment: ok, I got confuse about chrome console. Thx for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
dollar += '$';
```

is equal to

```
dollar = dollar + '$';
```

so first round dollar is equal to "$", so you will log it as it is, then you add another dollar to it. in next round you will see it "$$". like wise it comes to 6 dollar signs at the end, because you iterate it up to 6.