# Why is the result of `a * b` and `a *= b` for floating point numbers different

Tags: javascript

I borrowed this code from a question that was marked as duplicate and then deleted <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321028/wrong-value-when-using)</sup>, but because I was not able to find an exact duplicate to it I would like to create a new question for that.

I'm aware of the problems with floating-point arithmetic ([Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)), but this special case is still interesting.

The following two snippets look seemingly equal:

```js
let a = 860.42065
a *= 1/860.42065
console.log(a);
```

```js
let a = 860.42065
a = a * 1/860.42065
console.log(a);
```

So one could expect that those should have the same outcome because `a *= b` is seen as a shortcut for `a = a * b` ([How does += (plus equal) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826260/how-does-plus-equal-work)).

But the outcome of the two snippets can be different.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `*=` has a lower precedence than `* or /` as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

So, when we write `a *= 1 / b` it is not equal to `a = a * 1 / b;`

In case of `a *= 1/b` It will calculate 1/b first then multiply a with the result. On the other hand,

For `a = a * 1 / b` , as `*` and `/` are of same precedence and they evaluate from left to right, `a * 1` will be evaluated first then the result will be divided by `b`.

**Update** (Thanks to @Felix Kling)
This is how it works to be precise,

a *= 1/b actually implicitly groups the right hand side, therefore, it becomes, `a =  a * (1/b)`. That is why `1/b` is evaluated first and then multiplied by `a`.

Comment: Wile I can see how one might take the precedence of `*=` into account, I think it's a bit confusing/misleading, because if `*=` had a higher precedence, then it would be equivalent to `a = a * (1/b)` either (`(a *= 1)/b` would leave `a` unchanged).

Comment: To proof my point, consider `+=`: `a += 1/b` is in fact equivalent to `a = a + 1/b` even though `+=` has a lower precedence than `+` or `/`. What matters really is just the precedence and associativity of "underlying" operators involved. The assignment is only relevant insofar that the "combined" assignment "implicitly" groups the right hand side.

Comment: Ah I see, Thanks @Felix Kling. You mean, `a*=1/b ` is actually equivalent to `a = a*(1/b)` is that right?