# Sum of Array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm following a coursera course and I'm a bit stuck on a line of code. I understand what it does but not why.
The video explains how to get the avarage value of an Array.

I found this code online and its exactly the part that I don't get:

```
var numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40] // sums to 100
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  sum += numbers[i]
}
```

I don't get this part:

`sum+=numbers[i]`

I read it as sum = 0+4.

What am I missing?

Comment: `numbers` is a list with values at indices. you reference the values with an index/indices using `[]`, in this case i (which is 0, 1, 2, 3 - `numbers.length` is how many elements are in numbers)

Comment: _“I read it as sum = 0+4”_ — How? Where does the `4` come from? Do you know [what `+=` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)? Also see [How does += (plus equal) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6826260/4642212). Or is it `numbers[i]` you’re having trouble with? See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections).

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Comment: number[i] I didn't understand. Thank you for the link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what is says is "take whatever is in the `i` position of the `numbers` and add it to the value of `sum`".

So for example, if `i = 2`, then "whatever is in the `i` position of `numbers` would be 30.

To elaborate further, `var numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40]` can also be written as:

```
var numbers = [];
numbers[0] = 10;
numbers[1] = 20;
numbers[2] = 30;
numbers[3] = 40;
```

Hope this helps you understand better.

Comment: Oh! Ok I'mso  dumb. I just couldn't understand of find anywhere what that i is supposed to do. I know you put the index number there usually. Thank you so much

Comment: @GeorgeMunteanu No, you are not :)  we all had to start somewhere, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

In `sum += numbers[i]`, with operator `+=` means `sum = sum + numbers[i]`